# Spray Routes within Routes

Tags: spray

I have an app that is built using Spray.io.
I have a number of routes and at the moment I am repeating some of the routing logic within each route. I want to extract this logic out to a route higher up the chain while keeping each route/endpoint in a logically separate class.
This is an example of what I am currently trying...

ServiceActor...

```
def receive = runRoute(v1Routes)
```

V1Routes.scala (trait extending HttpService with other route traits)

```
val v1Routes =
  pathPrefix("v1") {
    authenticate(...) {
      myRoutes1 ~ myRoutes2
    }
  }
```

MyRoutes1.scala

```
val myRoutes1 =
  pathPrefix("route1") {...}
```

MyRoutes2.scala

```
val myRoutes2 =
  pathPrefix("route2") {...}
```

This compiles fine but the routes from MyRoutes1 and MyRoutes2 don't seem to get added into v1Routes as I would have hoped.

How do I implement this type of routing logic?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `lazy val`s instead?

Comment: It looks good otherwise. If the above doesn't help you probably need to post more surrounding code.

Comment: @jrudolph. Thanks! setting the two inner routes to lazy worked for me. Must be something to do with the logic within my routes. Can you add as answer?